# MapboxGL Marker Popup elements do not exist until the popup is toggled

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

In the webapp that I am currently developing I show a number of locations around a city square with markers. When tapped/clicked the markers display a popup with a 4 item menulist of actions - e.g. More Information, View Gallery etc.  On a typical city square I may show between 5 and 25 such markers.

The markers are created from JavaSript after the map of the square has been displayed. The code goes something like this

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.classList.add('popim000','popimNN');
//popimNN where NN is 01, 02 etc determines the map pin used

const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({element}).setLngLat(entry.latlng),
      popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({offset:25}),
      html = '<span class='laSpan xpop'>Read More</span>' + 
             '<span class='laSpan xpop'>View Gallery</span>' + 
             '<span class='laSpan xpop'>Not of interest</span>';


marker.addTo(mapBoxMapInstance);
popup.setHTML(html);
marker.setPopup(popup);
```

I have simplified and formatted the actual code in the interests of readability.  The problem I have run into is this. I want to detect `mousedown` and `touchstart` events on the spans above in order to do two things

1. Hide the popup
2. Display another HTML popup (not MapBox) that performs the required action - showing more information, displaying a picture gallery etc.

In order to do this I thought I could simply identify all relevant spans by issuing a `document.getElementsByClassName('xpop')`.  However, this does not work - it looks like MapBox does not actually render the popup HTML into the DOM until it has, well, popped up.

I can circumvent the problem by doing this

- First issue a `marker.togglePopup()` on each marker as it is generated and after it has been configured + attached to its parent map
- Then grab a reference to each `xpop` span while the popup is still on display.

This works but feels like a very hackish solution to me.  Is there another way to accomplish the same end result - linking the popup HTML `mousedown` and `touchstart` events with my own event handlers?

Comment: This question has not got answer.  I am guessing it is not going to get one.  I put in this comment to help anyone else trying to do something similar 

a better approach is to wire up the `open` event of the popup and assign the `touchstart`, `mousedown` event handlers for the menu items in the popup from there.  For good measure you can then remove that eventlistener so it never gets called again

Comment: You are permitted to (and encouraged to) write self-answers here - if you have a fix, it can still get an answer post!